# MCMC Metropolis-Hastings initial values

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

my posterior values that I obtained via Metroplis-Hasting are always around my initial values. For instance if I chose $\theta_0 =(1,2)$ my posterior values, after either taking mean or median, are around (1,2)

Any idea how to get the MH to explore more values?
For the proposal transition I am using T-distribution with  c$\Sigma$ covariance. constant c as suggested by Gelman. I tried to get the empirical bayes estimator and used them as initial values but it does not work.

CODE: USING R
     Trying to maximized log-likelihood function. ββ is of dimenssion 2

```
ββ[i,]   # Current value
log_post_curr= lik.b(ββ[i,])   # current log-likelihood values 
ββ[i+1,] =rmvt(n=1,delta=ββ[i+1,],ΣΣ=sig,df=3) : # Generating new value from      T-distribution centralized at the current value with known covariance matrix. df: degree of freedom 

log_post_prop= lik.b(ββ[i+1,]) # log-likelihood value for the proposed ββ

log_prop_curr= log(dmvt(ββ[i,],delta=ββ[i,],ΣΣ=sig,df=3))   # log T-value for the current ββ

log_prop_prop= log(dmvt(ββ[i+1,],delta=ββ[i+1,],ΣΣ=sig,df=3)) # log T-value for the proposed ββ

log_αα = log_prop_curr+log_post_prop - log_prop_prop-log_post_curr # log of the acceptance ratio

ϵϵ[i] = min(1,exp(log_αα))  # Acceptance ratio

u = runif(1)      # Generating a uniform value

if ((u <= ϵϵ[i]))

{
ββ[i,] <- ββ[i+1,]

counter=counter+1     # counting the number of accepted ββ

}
```

Comment: How long are you running the algorithm? Did you try values very far away, like (100, 200)?

Comment: I did run for 10000 iterations.

Comment: It is impossible to read your code in the comment. Please edit your question to read the code if you think it will be helpful.

Comment: The correct way is to *edit* your original question, and **not** add an answer. The code you have provided is *not* an answer, and should be removed and included in the original questions.

Comment: you can edit your **original** question by clicking on the edit button which is next to the *share* and *flag* button. Adding code in the comments is **not** helpful.

Comment: I repeat, you can edit your original question by clicking on the *edit* button at the bottom of your original question. Adding code in the comments is not helpful.

Comment: Done! Hope it's clear now

Comment: Please put some comments in the code to explain the steps, since it is a little unclear. Also, provide what language the code is in. You can do all this by editing the original question.

Comment: Should you not retain the current value,  if you do not accept the proposal? Perhaps proposal tuning or running for more samples (plus thinning, if you wish) is needed?

Comment: Can you write an explanation of your model and proposal (in words/equations besides the R code)?

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I fixed the errors and now it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

There are several coding issues:

1.The line of code

```
ββ[i+1,] =rmvt(n=1,delta=ββ[i+1,],ΣΣ=sig,df=3)
```

seems to show that the proposed value `ββ[i+1,]` is centred at itself: `delta=ββ[i+1,]` instead of being centred at the previous value `delta=ββ[i,]`

Similar corrections apply to the lines

```
log_prop_curr= log(dmvt(ββ[i,],delta=ββ[i,],ΣΣ=sig,df=3))   
# log T-value for the current ββ

log_prop_prop= log(dmvt(ββ[i+1,],delta=ββ[i+1,],ΣΣ=sig,df=3)) 
# log T-value for the proposed ββ
```

2.In addition, if the condition `u <= ϵ[i]`is not satisfied the previous value should be allocated to the new value

```
ββ[i+1,] <- ββ[i,]
```

while, if the condition `u <= ϵ[i]`is satisfied, the previous value should not be replaced by the new value:

```
β[i,] <- β[i+1,]
```

3.As an aside, although there is nothing wrong theoretically, you do not *need* to exponentiate the log Metropolis ratio

```
ϵϵ[i] = min(1,exp(log_αα))  # Acceptance ratio
```

as it is more stable and overflow-robust to compare a *log uniform* to the *log-ratio*:

```
if ((log(u) < log_αα))
```